# Declare arrays with different sizes in a C typedef struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

I know how to dynamic allocate a new array with `malloc`.
I wonder if there's a way to avoid that in this situation:

```
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE    256
#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE    128

typedef struct MyBuffer 
{
    volatile uint8_t RX[RX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    volatile uint8_t TX[TX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    volatile uint16_t RX_Head;
    volatile uint16_t RX_Tail;
    volatile uint16_t TX_Head;
    volatile uint16_t TX_Tail;
} MyBuffer_t;

typedef struct MyChannel
{
    // other stuff
    MyBuffer_t buffer;
} MyChannel_t;
```

then in my code I create several variables like this:

```
MyChannel_t ch1;
MyChannel_t ch2;
MyChannel_t ch3;
```

but I would like to set a different sizes of the arrays for each variable. It's ok to select among a small set, i.e.:

```
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE_S    32
#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE_S    16

#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE_M    128
#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE_M    64

#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE_L    256
#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE_L    128
```

Is there a way to achieve this *without* using `malloc`?

Comment: If you would declare the sizes in each source file, then include the typedef, then you can.

Comment: I would like to set the sizes for each `MyChannel_t` declared.

Comment: You can, if you declare them in different source files as per my suggestion. Otherwise, it is not possible.

Comment: Sidenote: Your `MyBuffer_t` should actually be named `My2Buffers_t`. I would recommend having only single buffer, head and tail in the structure, and then create distinct RX and TX instances that same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your buffers as pointers:

```
typedef struct MyBuffer 
{
    volatile uint8_t * RX;
    volatile uint8_t * TX;
    size_t rxSize;
    size_t txSize;
    volatile uint16_t RX_Head;
   ...
```

And then use separate static allocation for the buffers, and use them to initialize your object.

```
volatile uint8_t ch1_rx_buffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE_S];
volatile uint8_t ch1_tx_buffer[TX_BUFFER_SIZE_S];
MyChannel_t ch1 = { 
    .buffer = {
        ch1_rx_buffer, 
        ch1_tx_buffer, 
        sizeof ch1_rx_buffer, 
        sizeof ch1_tx_buffer,
         ... 
    }
}
```